# Hi, I want to know how to implemente a logic using PayPal in Django :)

Tags: django, view, paypal, payment

I am struggling with the logic, since I want to charge the customer before creating the "Reservacion" instance. So, the code in the view where I have the logic is here:

```
if (Cantidad_Mesas - Mesas_Ocupadas) >= Mesas_a_Ocupar_Cliente:
            nueva_reservacion = Reservacion.objects.create(Nombre=Nombre, Dia=Dia, Numero_Personas=Numero_Personas, Email=Email,
            Horario=Horario)  # Creamos una instancia del modelo Reservación directamente desde el "view.py".
            nueva_reservacion.save()  # Guardamos la nueva instancia creada en la base de datos.
            set_ = True  # Hacemos uso de esta bandera, para indicar que SÍ fue posible guardar la reservación en la BD.
return render(request, "reservacion/disponibilidad_horarios.html", {"disponibilidad": lista_horarios, "dia_reservacion": Dia})
```

But I want to do is, as I said, before creating the instance "Reservacion", I want to be able to built-in a payment using PayPal, so. Any Ideas?

Thank u, so much!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have any information about your PayPal implementation so far, so my suggestion is:

Create two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return, so this is when  you could create a reservation.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Hi Preston, Thank you so much! I decided to implement PayPal using the "Client-Side".